# как сделать переключение между функциями в javascript

Tags: javascript

Делаю мод на игру и не могу сделать что бы при нажатие на кнопку "num1"
менялась анимация this.standAnimation = "stand";
на this.standAnimation = "AHSS_stand_gun";
и на оборот
. Вот код :

```
        if (this.setup.myCostume.sex == SEX.FEMALE)
            {
                if (KeyCode
                this.standAnimation = "stand";
                this.setTeam2(1);
                return;
            }
            this.standAnimation = "stand_levi";
            this.setTeam2(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, добавить счетчик 1,2 на кнопку и от него плясать.Когда счетчик равен 1 выполнение одной функции, когда 2 другой.
Как пример:

```js
let button = document.querySelector(".button")

let i = 0;
function butClick() {
    
      if(i == 0){
        num1();
      }else {
        num2()
        i=0;
      }
    
}

function num1() {
  console.log("1");
  i++;
}

function num2() {
  console.log("2");
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <button class="button" onclick="butClick()">button</button>
```

Можно, конечно, красивее, но я умею только так...